# create net.tcp binding wcf service object in silverlight

Tags: wcf, silverlight, net.tcp

i have develop a silverlight application with wcf net.tcp binding. i want create an object of service in sliverlight. how it is possible. please help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, as far as I know, up to and including Silverlight 3, it supports only the `basicHttpBinding` (and possibly the webHttpBinding as well?). NetTCP is not supported, sorry.

Here's a [blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/silverlightws/archive/2009/03/20/what-s-new-with-web-services-in-silverlight-3-beta.aspx) by Yavor Georgiev (Program Manager, Silverlight Web Services Team) where he explains what's new in web services with Silverlight 3 - unfortunately, no mention of netTCP :-(

Marc

Answer (score 2):

Version Update,

Silverlight 4 now has the net.tcp binding

Answer (score 0):

Silverlight 4 supports tcp binding.
Some extended info:
http://tomasz.janczuk.org/2009/11/wcf-nettcp-protocol-in-silverlight-4.html